# Xcode: Save int CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

How can i save an **int** to CoreData?
And which type of Attribute should i choose?

```
int number = 0002202020202;
[newContact setValue:number forKey:@"phonenumber"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could save **only objects** in Core Data. With this in mind you should make a NSNumber object `NSNumber* number = @(0002202020202)`. For the Attribute type you could select some of the following Integer 16, Integer 32, Integer 64, depends on the range you want. 
Though if you really want to save the "phone number" my proposal is to use String as type.

Comment: Wow thank you very much. It works like i wanted it :)

Comment: This is slightly misleading. `setValue:forKey:` works only with objects, and by default, the Core Data generated accessor methods use objects. But you can select the "Use scalar accessors for primitive data types" when creating the NSManagedObject subclass. Then `newContact.phoneNumber = 123` would work.

Comment: well thank you @MartinR. I will try it but the other solution also works.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSNumber* number = @(0002202020202);
[newContact setValue:number forKey:@"phonenumber"];
```

Answer (score 1):

How is your core data model set up? I'd maybe consider storing that as a string instead of an int. If you'd like to save it as an int though, try choosing Integer 32. Does calling `setValue:forKey:` not work?